# Add image according to 4 returned records in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add an image (saved path in mysql - image from file on server) to my page according to 4 rows returned. There will always be 4 rows returned from db.

My problem is that it shows the same image (main with 3 thumbnails) in all 4 image holders. I've used the following to add the images ...

First my php function -

```
//Get all images within a specific album...
function get_images($vehicleid) {
    //$vehicle_id = (int)$vehicle_id;

    $images = array();

    $image_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `images`.`vehicle_id`='$vehicleid'");

    $result = $image_query;

    if (!$result){
       echo 'Error in loading vehicle adverts. Please refresh page and try again';
       exit();
    }

    while($images_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_query)) {
        $images[] = array(
            'imageid' => $images_row['image_id'],
            'branch' => $images_row['branch'],
            'vehicleid' => $images_row['vehicle_id'],
            'timestamp' => $images_row['timestamp'],
            'ext' => $images_row['ext'],
            'imagenum' => $images_row['imagenum']
        );

        //This returns main image and 3 thumbs, but only image from first record is returned..
                     return $images;
    }
        //return $images;
                    //When runned from here, main image is from 1st, then 2nd, 3rd etc row returned, but it loads each rows image as a main and the thumbs the same image...
}
```

The code I have used to load the images is as follow ...

```
<?php
    //Get images...
$images = get_images($vehicleid);

if (empty($images)) {
    ?>

    <table id="thumbnails">
        <tr>
            <td>                                        
                <div>
                <a href="testdrive.php" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="uploads/noimage.jpg" width="600px" height="400px" title="Sorry, No Image Available Yet" /></a>
                </div>                    
            </td>
            <td>
                <table width="350px">
                    <tr height="50px">
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="mainimages" align="center" style="font-size:14px">
                                <?php echo $year, ' ', $manufacturer, ' ', $modelrange, ' ', $modelder, '.', '<br />', '<br />', 'This beautiful ', $colour, ' ',$manufacturer, ' only has ', $mileage, ' kilometres  with a service history and is selling for ', '<strong>ONLY R ', $price, '. </strong>', '<br />', '<br />', 'It features ', $comments, '<br />', '<br />', 'This vehicle is available NOW from our ', '<a href="testdrive.php" style="text-decoration:none">', 'Tata - ', $branch, ' branch.</a>'; ?> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="mainimages" align="center" style="font-size:14px">
                                 <?php //MAIN IMAGE HERE FROM RECORD 1 (Note from upload folder, not thumbs as below)...
                                 echo '<a href="delete_image.php?vehicle_id='.$vehicleid.'"><img src="images/delete.png" title="Delete Advert" /></a>'; 
                                 ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="uploads/thumbs/noimage.jpg" title="Sorry, No Image Available Yet" width="100px" height="100px" /><img src="uploads/thumbs/noimage.jpg" title="Sorry, No Image Available Yet" width="100px" height="100px" /><img src="uploads/thumbs/noimage.jpg" title="Sorry, No Image Available Yet" width="100px" height="100px" />

                <p style="height:10px"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
        //echo '<img src="uploads/noimage.jpg" />';
        } else {
            //Display images thumbs...
            foreach ($images as $image) {
    ?>

    <table id="thumbnails">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php 
                    //Add image title to the right of main image...
                    echo '<a href="testdrive.php" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="uploads/', $image['vehicleid'], '/', $image['imageid'], '.', $image['ext'], '" title="Uploaded ', date('D M Y / h:i', $image['timestamp']), ' - ', $year, ' ', $manufacturer, ' ', $modelrange, ' ', $modelder, '.', 'This beautiful ', $colour, ' ',$manufacturer, ' only has ', $mileage, ' kilometres and is selling for ', 'ONLY R ', $price, '.', '" width="600px" height="400px" /></a>'; 
                ?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table width="350px">
                    <tr height="50px">
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="mainimages" align="center" style="font-size:14px">
                                <?php 
                                echo $year, ' ', $manufacturer, ' ', $modelrange, ' ', $modelder, '.', '<br />', '<br />', 'This beautiful ', $colour, ' ',$manufacturer, ' only has ', $mileage, ' kilometres with a service history and is selling for ', '<strong>ONLY R ', $price, '. </strong>', '<br />', '<br />', 'It features ', $comments, '<br />', '<br />', 'This vehicle is available NOW from our ', '<a href="testdrive.php" style="text-decoration:none">', 'Tata - ', $branch, ' branch.</a>'; 
                                ?> 
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div id="mainimages" align="center" style="font-size:14px">
                                 <?php
                                 echo '<a href="delete_image.php?vehicle_id='.$vehicleid.'"><img src="images/delete.png" title="Delete Advert" /></a>'; 
                                 ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                <?php //THIS WHERE I NEED TO START LOADING THE CORRECT IMAGES - THIS SHOULD BE IMAGE RETURNED FROM RECORD 2...
                echo '<a href="testdrive.php" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $image['vehicleid'], '/', $image['imageid'], '.', $image['ext'], '" title="Uploaded ', date('D M Y / h:i', $image['timestamp']), ' - ', $year, ' ', $manufacturer, ' ', $modelrange, ' ', $modelder, '.', 'This beautiful ', $colour, ' ',$manufacturer, ' only has ', $mileage, ' kilometres and is selling for ', 'ONLY R ', $price, '.', '" onclick="showImage("uploads/', $image['vehicleid'], '/', $image['imageid'], '.', $image['ext'], '" width="100px" height="100px")" /></a>';

    //THIS SHOULD BE IMAGE RETURNED FROM RECORD 3...
                echo '<a href="testdrive.php" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $image['vehicleid'], '/', $image['imageid'], '.', $image['ext'], '" title="Uploaded ', date('D M Y / h:i', $image['timestamp']), ' - ', $year, ' ', $manufacturer, ' ', $modelrange, ' ', $modelder, '.', 'This beautiful ', $colour, ' ',$manufacturer, ' only has ', $mileage, ' kilometres and is selling for ', 'ONLY R ', $price, '.', '" onclick="showImage("uploads/', $image['vehicleid'], '/', $image['imageid'], '.', $image['ext'], '" width="100px" height="100px")" /></a>';

    //THIS SHOULD BE IMAGE RETURNED FROM RECORD 4...
                echo '<a href="testdrive.php" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $image['vehicleid'], '/', $image['imageid'], '.', $image['ext'], '" title="Uploaded ', date('D M Y / h:i', $image['timestamp']), ' - ', $year, ' ', $manufacturer, ' ', $modelrange, ' ', $modelder, '.', 'This beautiful ', $colour, ' ',$manufacturer, ' only has ', $mileage, ' kilometres and is selling for ', 'ONLY R ', $price, '.', '" onclick="showImage("uploads/', $image['vehicleid'], '/', $image['imageid'], '.', $image['ext'], '" width="100px" height="100px")" /></a>';
                ?>

                <p style="height:10px"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
            }
        }
    }
   ?>
```

Anyone have any idea how I can return the correct images to their respective html holders?

Thanx guys.

Comment: return $images; is placed inside the while loop, so it only runs once and returns a single image data. There maybe other errors than this.

Comment: How you define main image and thumbs ? what is imagenum ? if imagenum=1, then it is main image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer is not correct, but still valid because you never use "imagenum". And return still must be outside the while.

Anyway the reason you get always the same image is that you're using always the same array element.

Try:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($images as $image) {
    If($i=0) { 
?>

<table id="thumbnails">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php 
                //Add image title to the right of main image...
                echo '<a href="testdrive.php" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="uploads/', $image['vehicleid'], '/', $image['imageid'], '.', $image['ext'], '" title="Uploaded ', date('D M Y / h:i', $image['timestamp']), ' - ', $year, ' ', $manufacturer, ' ', $modelrange, ' ', $modelder, '.', 'This beautiful ', $colour, ' ',$manufacturer, ' only has ', $mileage, ' kilometres and is selling for ', 'ONLY R ', $price, '.', '" width="600px" height="400px" /></a>'; 
            ?>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table width="350px">
                <tr height="50px">
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="mainimages" align="center" style="font-size:14px">
                            <?php 
                            echo $year, ' ', $manufacturer, ' ', $modelrange, ' ', $modelder, '.', '<br />', '<br />', 'This beautiful ', $colour, ' ',$manufacturer, ' only has ', $mileage, ' kilometres with a service history and is selling for ', '<strong>ONLY R ', $price, '. </strong>', '<br />', '<br />', 'It features ', $comments, '<br />', '<br />', 'This vehicle is available NOW from our ', '<a href="testdrive.php" style="text-decoration:none">', 'Tata - ', $branch, ' branch.</a>'; 
                            ?> 
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="mainimages" align="center" style="font-size:14px">
                             <?php
                             echo '<a href="delete_image.php?vehicle_id='.$vehicleid.'"><img src="images/delete.png" title="Delete Advert" /></a>'; 
                             ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <?php $i=1; } else {//THIS WHERE I NEED TO START LOADING THE CORRECT IMAGES - THIS SHOULD BE IMAGE RETURNED FROM RECORD 2...
            echo '<a href="testdrive.php" style="text-decoration:none"><img src="uploads/thumbs/', $image['vehicleid'], '/', $image['imageid'], '.', $image['ext'], '" title="Uploaded ', date('D M Y / h:i', $image['timestamp']), ' - ', $year, ' ', $manufacturer, ' ', $modelrange, ' ', $modelder, '.', 'This beautiful ', $colour, ' ',$manufacturer, ' only has ', $mileage, ' kilometres and is selling for ', 'ONLY R ', $price, '.', '" onclick="showImage("uploads/', $image['vehicleid'], '/', $image['imageid'], '.', $image['ext'], '" width="100px" height="100px")" /></a>';

            ?>



<?php
        }
    }
}
?>
            <p style="height:10px"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Or something similar (it's difficult to write code in the stackoverflow editor).

Comment: it generates parse errors. how we come to know always first image is main image ?

Comment: I suppose I missed a `}`. I should use a PHP editor, but I hope Andre Oosthuizen could do the corrections...

Comment: Thanx for now UFO and GBD. I'll try the code quickly, let you know in 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanx giys, will try and let you know in 10 minutes.

Comment: `code`<?php
$i=0;
foreach ($images as $image) {
    If($i=0) {
  //Add main image to div tag,image holder...
  
  //How do I increase the value of $i to 1?
  //How would I use that value of then? Inside this if statement or do a second if?
  
 }
}
?>

Comment: Look at this line:
`<?php $i=1; } else {//THIS WHERE I NEED TO START LOADING THE CORRECT IMAGES - THIS SHOULD BE IMAGE RETURNED FROM RECORD 2...`
$i is set at 1, so you're not loading the main image anymore. You don't need to increase $i more than this because you treat the 3 thumbs in the same way (notice that in the else there's only one echo that is cycled 3 times by the foreach on the top).

Anyway if you need to increase $i more than one time use $i++...

Comment: I'll explain the basic idea of the algorithm. You have 4 images in an array. You cycle this array, but the first element in the array should be treated differently from the others. How can you know if you're using the first element? If $i is still 0 you're using the first element. After the use of this element you set $i=1, so that you know all the others elements shouldn't be considered the first ones.

Comment: I've actually found a work around. All images are saved with the image_id as its caption. I've just added $imageid + 1, +2 etc. worked a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`return $images;` must be outside the while or the cycle never will be completed.

I suppose the code doesn't work because there's an error in the DB or in the design of the data. For example, what "imagenum" means in the DB? Should you use this value for retrieve the image?

Comment: Thanx ufo,When I run the code ourside the loop it returns all 4 records, but it uploads record 1 main image with the 3 thumbs being the same image, then rec 2 etc.

Comment: imagenum is the call to image_id in my field. All records is returned, I've echoed out all values, so data connection and such is all fine.

Comment: @AndreOosthuizen how you define main image and thumb image ?

Comment: [link]http://www.surf4cars.co.za/showroom/Vehicle_Details.aspx?VehicleID=154399&ref=showroom If you have a look at this link, it will show you what I need, main vehicle image with 3 smaller thumbnails below that.

Comment: @AndreOosthuizen always first image is main image ?

Comment: @GBD, I have a 600x400 image from a folder called Uploads. All main images is stored here. Within Uploads I have a folder called thumbs with 100x100 images used as thumbnails.

Comment: @GBD, yes, first image is always the main image from my uploads folder 600x400px. the other 3 returned rows will load from the thumbs folder.

Comment: I am talking about database. when you fetch from db alway first reocord is main image ?

Comment: Yes, first record is ALWAYS the main image. If you have a look inside the div tags, I'm uploading the main image first (1st record) then the thumbnails (2-4 recod rows)

Comment: @ufo, I got the concept of using the If($i=0) { } part, whil most definitely help. I will encase the div tags inside here depending on which record is returned. How do I increment the counter though .. If($i=0) {div1 - imagemain here} increase counter?how If($i=1) {div2-imagethumb here} and so on. Will it come after the div1 code?